# OpenCV create TrackBar RGB and change image color when change value trackbar

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb

In OpenCV i can create trackbar of RGB but my problem is : **how can i change color of image when change value RGB on trackbar ?**

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do. Just to clarify; you want to change the color of an image how?

Comment: Yes, I load image and change value of red, green or blue. The image will be redder or greener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a python example on how to do this on the OpenCV websites. You could do a very similar thing in C++ without too much difficulty

The python tutorial is here:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html

To do this in C++ replace the python commands with C++ alternatives. most of them you can find on this page here:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html